# Why does installing applications freeze my DroidX running Froyo 2.2?

Tags: installation, performance, system-freeze

I noticed recently that installing any applications caused my Droid X (Stock rooted Froyo 2.2) to freeze for a while - I mean completely freeze, can't go to home screen or pull down Notification bar or anything.

It may **possibly** be correllated time-wise with installing Lookout Security app, but I am not certain if the time matches.

This seems to be 100% unrelated to a specific installer application I use, but I haven't conclusively ruled it out.

1. Could this plausibly be caused by Lookout? If so I'll try to un-install it to verify
2. If it's caused by Lookout, are there any suggestions for making this less painful? I was thinking along the lines of loweing "nice" priority for Lookout scanner process somehow if Android allows that, being based on Linux.
3. If not Lookout, what else could it possibly be and what troubleshooting steps can I take short of flashing back to SBF and trying to install my apps again from backup?

**Details:**

- Rooted Stock Froyo 2.2 on DroidX.
- Source of installation is irrelevant (Android Market, or Amazon Market, or GetJar). I didn't test SD/Dropbox APK installs, but fairly certain that they are freezing as well.
- I have several installer apps available, but default to stock one. *I don't know how to un-default it to test if it's a specific installer.*
- As noted, I have Lookout Security running, set to scan any installed .apks.

  It is **possible** that the freezing didn't happen or was much quicker before I installed it, but I don't have proof. Also, installing NUMEROUS updates of Lookout didn't affect the freezing.
- Freezing is 100% independent on what else is running - I can kill 100% of non-Market apps and the freezing will still happen with almost full memory available
- Freeze period **seems** to be correllated to .apk size, but I don't have a firm proof. Usually lasts between 30 secs and 2 mins.
- This seems to be NOT related to having to **start** other apps (e.g. Amazon Market/GetJar) that are started by "Application Installed"/"Application changed" intents, since the freeze happens for EVERY app installed among several, not just the first one in a row.

Comment: I would definitely suspect Lookout.

Comment: Agree to Matthew. Lookout possible scan the apk if its malicious.

Comment: @Leandros - not **possibly** - it **definitely** scans. That's its main advertized functionality (well one I have enabled, at least). What I don't get is why it freezes the system so completely. PC antiviruses are usually able to scan files in background without fully blocking the OS

Comment: @DVK: A pc is way faster. :) And if you don't have a dualcore, multithreading is not very good supported.